# PDFLib installed but not available in code or visible through phpinfo()

Tags: php, apache, pdflib

I think I did quite a good job on installing PDFlib on a system (Ubuntu 18.04) but something's not totally right yet. What I did so far:

- Followed the instructions here: https://www.pdflib.com/fileadmin/pdflib/pdf/support/PDFlib-in-PHP-HowTo.pdf
- Downloaded the correct `php_pdflib.so` file and placed it in the extension directory I got through `phpinfo()`
- Added `extension=php_pdflib.so` in my `php.ini`
- Ran a `sudo systemctl restart apache2` to restart Apache and reload extensions
- Checked with `php -i | grep PDF` whether the binary was loaded or not, result seems positive

  ```
  PDFlib  
  PDFlib Support => enabled  
  PDFlib GmbH Binary-Version => 9.2.0
  ```

Now, when I run `phpinfo();` from the web side through a file, there is no mention of PDFlib at all. When I run it through CLI, everything seems to be okay.

I also tried creating a new PDFlib() instance through CLI and web. CLI works, web doesn't.

Did I miss something in the install process?

Comment: Check to see which INI file is being used for CLI and which one is being used for  your web server. It sounds like you updated the one for CLI but not the one for the web server.

Comment: Good point. Updated my `/etc/php/7.3/fpm/php.ini`accordingly, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: And you restarted your server after making the change?

Comment: I restarted Apache if you mean that when you write "server". I did not reboot the machine itself. Shouldn't be necessary, or am I wrong?

Comment: That is what I meant,  your web server. Create a PHP page that just does `phpinfo();` and use your browser to view it. Check the value of `Loaded Configuration File` and make sure it matches the INI file you modified.

Comment: Ah yeah, that fits. Will have a look at it nevertheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also tried creating a new PDFlib() instance through CLI and web. CLI works, web doesn't.

this is a typical situation. The PHP CLI and the PHP within the web server could have different configuration. So please check the extension_dir as well which the php.ini which was loaded in your web server phpinfo() output. Then you have do the the same configuration. Please check as well the PHP/Webserver log file for any error messages. Maybe it might be NTS/TS (threading) issue as well, but this will be mentioned in the error message.

Comment: Hi Rainer, thanks for joining in. I compared my php.ini files and they are identical except for some disabled functions in the php-fpm version. Extension folders are also the same and both are using NTS versions. I also checked all the logs I could find related to PHP/Apache but there were no clues either. Any further ideas?

Comment: Hi @flomei you might check in the phpinfo() output the entries for:  "Configuration File (php.ini) Path", **"Loaded Configuration File"**, "Scan this dir for additional .ini files", "Additional .ini files parsed". Is your edited php.ini within this list? And contain the path set in your **extension_dir** the `php_pdflib.so`?

Comment: Thanks Rainer, this helped me to think about all the pieces again. Got it working now.

Answer (score 1):

Being not a good engineer today, I did several things at once, so I can't tell what exactly worked out in the end. Will write down my steps nevertheless, as it works now.

- I double checked the configuration file paths and files through `php -i` and a `phpinfo();` to see the differences between CLI and web frontend.
- I removed the `extension=php_pdflib` from both php.ini files
- I moved the `php_pdflib.so` from the extension directory one level up, it now lives in `/usr/lib/php` directly
- I also renamed it to `phplib.so` (but that was more to break things on purpose and see what happens
- I created a `30-pdflib.ini` file in `/etc/php/7.3/fpm/conf.d` and wrote only `extension=/usr/lib/php/pdflib.so` in it
- Added that line to `/etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini` to see if there's a difference
- I tried restarting Apache2 several times, but `phpinfo()` did not show any changes for the loaded configuration files or modules
- I did a `sudo reboot`
- Checked again and now PDFlib is loaded for CLI as well as for web

So, not sure if a hard reboot really fixed this, but it seems to me like that. Maybe this helps someone else.